# Degree placement before an adjective

Tags: questions

Can we use the word *little* in front of an adjective the same way we can use the word in front of an uncountable noun? For example we can say:

> "Give me a little money"

Can we also say:

> *The movie is a **little** funny.*

Comment: I’ve edited your question to clean it up. Please let me know if I’ve misconstrued your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are some idiomatic uses which follow this pattern; *It's a little strange (that you should ask)*, *(This looks like being) a little awkward*.

Sometimes little is expressed as *a little bit* e.g.*this example is a little bit different*.

Your example, about the movie, only really works with *funny* - meaning *peculiar*, not with *funny* meaning *makes you laugh*.

It is not all adjectives which will take *little* and *little bit* in this way. And it is probably only experience which will guide you in understanding which ones will, I'm afraid to say. Of course some of the distinguished grammarians on the site may be able to provide a schema, but as simply a native speaker I am unaware of one.

Comment: But "sorta funny" would imply it's humorous but not a real rib tickler.

Comment: @HotLicks If not perhaps the most erudite literary critique available.